# How to fix gaps/cracks between pavers

Tags: pavers

I had pavers installed on my patio about 8 years ago. I recently noticed that in some spots there is a visible, 1/8" crack forming between the pavers.

How do I go about sealing/fixing this? I've read online that pavers typically have some kind of sand poured between them to hold them in place, but the material between the pavers seems to be firm and hard (like a grout of some kind) rather than loose or gritty (like I would expect sand to be).

Is this an easy fix, where I can just apply some compound or sand mixture to the gap?

Thanks

[image: A crack between pavers]

Comment: unfortunately this will not stop, the foundation is not solid

Comment: Sometimes they just brush in dry cement with/without colour and let natural moisture set it.

Answer (score 1):

Sand is the most common way to install pavers but they can definitely be grouted in place too. The rounded corners would lead me to believe your pavers were grouted. To fix this, you'll need a grout saw/removal tool  and you'll have to remove the grout that's cracked. The more you remove along the crack, the better the new grout will hold. Get a matching grout from your home store/tile store and follow the directions. You could do some hack job like using caulk to fill in the crack but we try to suggest the right way to do a project.